# AngularFire2 methods which return a promise do not work with fromPromise

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs5, angularfire2

I am working on an AngularFire2 application and want to implement basic authentication. The authentication itself works so far but, additionally I want to create a user object upon registration, so that each user has a profile in the database. The main issue here is that almost all methods on the AngularFire2 service return promises. On the other hand the db service works with observables and the combination of `firebase.Promise` and observables somehow doesn't work as expected.

So for instance, this does't work:

```
Observable.fromPromise(() => this.auth$.createUser(credentials))
```

This results in an error saying `Argument of type 'Promise<FirebaseAuthState>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<{}>'`.

The same applies for the `set` method on a `db.object`. I don't know how to fix this issue.

My idea was to work with the promises but at some point I have to cast from an observable to a promise then. This is what I have:

**auth.service.ts**

```
register(credentials: ICredentials): firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
  return this.auth$.createUser(credentials)
    .then((response: FirebaseAuthState) => this.userService.createUserEntity(response))
    .then(() => this.postSignIn())
    .catch((error: Error) => this.onError(error));
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
createUserEntity(response: FirebaseAuthState): Promise<boolean> {
  this.user = this.db.object(`/users/${response.uid}`);

  return this.user
    .take(1)
    .filter((snapshot: Snapshot) => !snapshot.$exists())
    .mergeMap(() => this.createUser(response))
    .toPromise();
}

private createUser(response: FirebaseAuthState): Observable<any> {
  const { email, displayName, photoURL, providerId } = response.auth;

  return Observable.of(new User(email, displayName, photoURL, providerId))
    .mergeMap((user) => this.saveUserEntity(user));
}

private saveUserEntity(user): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.user.set(user).then(() => {
      console.log('RESOLVE');
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see in the `saveUserEntity`, I even tried to work around by creating a promise myself and resolving it. But somehow this never resolves in the source promise chain in `register()`. The `console.log` in `saveUserEntity` is called but it never goes up again, and the promise chain doesn't continue to work. Again, `fromPromise` somehow has the same behavior. However, I can replace the body of `saveUserEntity` with `Promise.resolve(1)` and everything works. Somehow the `this.user.set` messes things up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately some of the promises returned by Angularfire are `Promise<FirebaseAuthState>`, you have to cast those promises. So this will work:

```
Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>this.auth$.createUser(credentials))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I have tried `Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>this.auth$.createUser(credentials)).do(console.log);` and the `do` is not called.

Comment: try `Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>>this.auth$.createUser(c‌​redentials)).do(
    function (x)   { console.log('Do Next:', x); },
    function (err) { console.log('Do Error:', err); },
    function ()    { console.log('Do Completed'); }
  ).subscribe()` You have to subscribe

Comment: Why do I have to subscribe? So `fromPromise` returns a cold observable?

Comment: Yes, you always have to subscribe

Comment: Ok, what about my `user.service`, there is the same problem. I am using `mergeMap`, and this does subscribe for me automatically right? Somehow that isnt working either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127112/discussion-between-lordtribual-and-fabio-antunes).